# What is the function of I()?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I found the following code on the internet

`mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ weight + I(weight^2) + foreign, auto)`

What is the function `I()`? It seems that the result of `weight^2` is same as `I(weight^2)`.

Comment: Did you read `help(I)`?  If not, please read it.  If so, please tell us what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Do note that just comparing `weight^2` with `I(weight^2)` **at the command prompt** is not the appropriate test for their similarity when used in a formula. There, because there are additional formula parsing and interpretation conventions being applied, the two calls *are* different.

Comment: `?formula` is another additional good resource with examples on how to use `I()` in formula.

Answer (score 12):

The function of `I()` is to *isolate* terms in formulae from the usual formula parsing & syntax. There are other uses of `I()` in data frames where it helps create objects that have or inherit from class `"AsIs"` which allows the embedding of objects without the usual conversion that takes place.

In the formula case, as that is what you specifically ask about, `^` is a special formula operator which indicates crossing of the terms to the `n`th degree where `n` is given following the operator like so: `^n`. As such `^` does not have it's usual arithmetic interpretation in a formula. (Likewise, the `-`, `+`, `/` and `*` operators also have special formula meanings and as a result `I()` is required to use them to isolate them from the formula parsing tools.)

In the specific example you give (which I'll illustrate using an in-built data set `trees`), if you forget to use `I()` round a the quadratic term, R will, in this case, ignore that term completely as `Volume` (`weight` in your example) is already in the model and you are asking for multi-way interactions of the variable with itself, which is not a quadratic term.

First without `I()`:

```
> lm(Height ~ Volume + Volume^2, data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Volume + Volume^2, data = trees)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       Volume  
    69.0034       0.2319
```

Notice how only the `Volume` term is in the formula? The correct specification for a quadratic model (actually it may not be, see below) is

```
> lm(Height ~ Volume + I(Volume^2), data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Volume + I(Volume^2), data = trees)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       Volume  I(Volume^2)  
   65.33587      0.47540     -0.00314
```

I said it may not be correct; this is due to correlation between `Volume` and Volume^2`. An identical but more stable fit can be achieved by the use of orthogonal polynomials, which`poly()` can produce for you. So the more stable speficiation would be:

```
> lm(Height ~ poly(Volume, 2), data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ poly(Volume, 2), data = trees)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  poly(Volume, 2)1  poly(Volume, 2)2  
          76.000            20.879            -5.278
```

Note that the fit is identical to the earlier model though with different coefficient estimates as the input data are different (orthogonal polynomials vs raw polynomials). You can see this by their `summary()` output if you don't believe me:

```
> summary(lm(Height ~ poly(Volume, 2), data = trees))

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ poly(Volume, 2), data = trees)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.2266  -3.6728  -0.0745   2.4073   9.9954 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       76.0000     0.9322  81.531  < 2e-16 ***
poly(Volume, 2)1  20.8788     5.1900   4.023 0.000395 ***
poly(Volume, 2)2  -5.2780     5.1900  -1.017 0.317880    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 5.19 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3808, Adjusted R-squared: 0.3365 
F-statistic: 8.609 on 2 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.001219 

> summary(lm(Height ~ Volume + I(Volume^2), data = trees))

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Volume + I(Volume^2), data = trees)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.2266  -3.6728  -0.0745   2.4073   9.9954 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 65.335867   4.110886  15.893 1.52e-15 ***
Volume       0.475398   0.246279   1.930   0.0638 .  
I(Volume^2) -0.003140   0.003087  -1.017   0.3179    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 5.19 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3808, Adjusted R-squared: 0.3365 
F-statistic: 8.609 on 2 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.001219
```

Note the difference in the *t*-tests for the linear and quadratic terms in the models. This is where the orthogonality of the input polynomial terms helps.

To really see what `^` does in a formula (in case the terminology in `?formula` is not something you are familiar with, consider this model:

```
> lm(Height ~ (Girth + Volume)^2, data = trees)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ (Girth + Volume)^2, data = trees)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)         Girth        Volume  Girth:Volume  
    75.40148      -2.29632       1.86095      -0.05608
```

As there are two terms in `(...)^2`, the formula parsing code converts that into the main effects of the two variables plus their 2nd-order interaction. That model could be more succinctly written as `Height ~ Girth * Volume`, but `^` helps when you want higher-order interactions or interactions among a larger number of variables.

Comment: Does `I()` allow you to construct additional variables for the regression like `I(log(Volume + 1))` and can you even use these new variables in interactions? e.g. `(I(log(Volume + 1)) + Girth)^2`

Comment: Ah, ok, it looks like this is explained in `?formula` and not `?I`.